# Как поправить кодировку в XML документе?

Tags: python, notepad++

При записи изменений в XML документ

```
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank updated="yes">Москва</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank updated="yes">Санкт-Петербург</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
<country name="Panama">
    <rank updated="yes">Новосибирск</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
</country>
```

с помощью метода

```
tree.write('output.xml')
```

слетает кириллица,

```
 from xml.dom.minidom import *
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 import ConfigParser

 conf = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
 conf.read('C:\config.conf')# Путь до файла указывается в конфиге

 path = conf.get('Path:', 'path')

 xml2 = parse(path)
 tree = ET.parse(path)
 root = tree.getroot()

 i = 1
 for rank in root.iter('rank'):
     if i in [1]: 
        new_rank = 'Москва'
        rank.text = str(new_rank)
        rank.set('updated', 'yes')
 i += 1
 tree.write(path)
```

строчка

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1251" standalone="true"?>

в начале документа удаляется. Документ открываю в Notpade++ в нём и работаю.

Comment: А `tree.write` это чей объект вызывает? Описывайте, пожалуйста, подробнее. А так, нужен [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @gil9red, Чего-то мне кажется, что это *elementtree*, ну оно по умолчанию скорее всего в UTF-8 пишет. Да и Microsoft же уже поправил Notepad, чтобы работал с UTF-8.

Comment: @gil9red Дополнил.

Comment: @0andriy тут суть меняет причём без возвратно именно в Notepad если открыть в EA то без этой строчки, что в вопросе вся кириллица отображается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы при сохранении XML в файл добавлялась строчка `<?xml version="1.0" ...` нужно в метод [write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) передавать флаг `xml_declaration`:

```
...
tree.write(path, xml_declaration=True)
```

В этом же методе можно указать название кодировки, что будет записана в декларации XML:

```
...
tree.write(path, encoding='WINDOWS-1251', xml_declaration=True)
```